# What to append to a path to make it point to the file system root?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

I have some path, let's say `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\`. I would like to find such a string, that when appended (from the right side), will make this path point to `C:\`.

Well, that is easy if the path is set; I could just make it `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\..\..\..\`.

What I am looking for however, is a **fixed string** that would work every time, no matter how the initial path looks (and especially how long it is). Does Windows offer some tricks to help this? If it is impossible to achieve, then it's a valid answer.

Bonus points: can I refer to a different hard drive this way?

Comment: Absurdly long sequence of `..\..\..\..\..\` seems to be a good-enough workaround, since `C:\..\` equals `C:\`, but I am curious if I could do it in a cleaner and more reliable way.

Comment: Any reason why you can't just write `C:\` directly?

Comment: `Cannot find path 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\C:' because it does not exist.` it just doesn't work if you meant this.

Comment: No, I mean, why do you need to use a relative path if you just want to go to the root? Why is your code structured so that you need to come up with workarounds like this? Why not just reference root directly, and not deal with this path concatenation?

Comment: Ah, well, I am working with some system that stores binaries in a predefined directory. Normally I ask it to run some of them by providing just exe file names, so it finds them in there. However, in my case I really want it to execute powershell.exe, which cannot be done in any other way than exploiting the path upwards.

Comment: I hardly have control over how the binaries are resolved.

Comment: `for %I in ("C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell") do echo %~dI`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *fixed* string is not an option, but it's easy to *dynamically* construct one for a given path of arbitrary length.

Taking advantage of the fact that `*`, when applied to *string* on the LHS, replicates that string a given number of times (e.g., `'x' * 3` yields `xxx`):

```sh
# Sample input path.
$path = 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell'

# Concatenate as many '..\' instances as there are components in the path.
$relativePathToRoot = '..\' * $path.Split('\').Count
$absolutePathToRoot = Join-Path $path $relativePathToRoot

# Sample output
[pscustomobject] @{
  RelativePathToRoot = $relativePathToRoot
  AbsolutePathToRoot = $absolutePathToRoot
}
```

<sup>Note: On Unix, use `'../' * $path.Split('/').Count`; for a cross-platform solution, use `"..$([IO.Path]::DirectorySeparatorChar)" * $path.Split([IO.Path]::DirectorySeparatorChar).Count`; for a solution that can handle either separator on either platform (and uses `/` in the result), use `'../' * ($path -split '[\\/]').Count`</sup>

Output:

```sh
RelativePathToRoot AbsolutePathToRoot
------------------ ------------------
..\..\..\..\       C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell..\..\..\..\
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Convert-Path` to resolve/consolidate the given path, then keep adding `..` until you reach the root of the volume:

```
# Grab current location from `$pwd` automatic variable
$path = "$pwd"

# Calculate path root 
$root = [System.IO.Path]::GetPathRoot($path)

while((Convert-Path $path) -ne $root){
  # We haven't reached the root yet, keep backing up
  $path = Join-Path $path '..'
}
```

`$path` now contains `C:\Current\Relative\Path\..\..\..` and you can now do:

```
& path\to\myBinary.exe (Join-Path $path.Replace("$pwd","").TrimStart('\') targetfile.ext)
```

`$path.Replace("$pwd", "")` gives us just `\..\..\..`, and `TrimStart('\')` removes the leading path separator so as to make the path relative, so the resulting string passed to the binary will be `..\..\..\targetfile.ext`

Comment: This doesn't really solve my problem. I am looking for a constant string that would work for any path. I'll update my post to make it clearer.

Comment: @radrow Why is it important that it's a fixed/static string?

Comment: I would like to have a reliable way of making some executable file resolver run a file out of its predefined binary directory. The problem is, this directory can vary and I would like not to depend on it.

Comment: @radrow My answer clearly takes the current path into account to ensure you always get a relative path that reaches the path root, it's not gonna get more reliable :)

Comment: Okay, I see I could use it to hack it over.

Answer (score 0):

The root is available in the FileInfo object.

```
PS C:\src\t> (Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\').PSDrive.Root
C:\
```